# OSGI- Bundles autostart/stop of bundles

Tags: osgi

i am new to osgi framework. can anyone help me how to start/stop osgi bundle(s) auto when osgi   framework starts. i am stuck in this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

check OSGi Core Specification 4.2+: 8 Start Level Service Specification for more details.

If you use Equinox: check this [blog](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/) for details. For felix - [here](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html)

Best regards,
Dmytro

Comment: Could you add an explicit answer, rather than just referring to other pages?